# Maths Capture needs adding to two tabs on same html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have attached a snippet showing code. I am trying to add two Math Capture on two different tab which are on the same HTML page.

So on the NEWS tab the capture is working perfectly but on the CONTACT tab the Math question does not show up just a blank white box.

But the submit button in the contact tab is working from the News tab but its wrong as its using the math question from the News tab.

Im not sure how to get this to work on both pages??

Hope you can help??

Thanks

Tim

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


var total;

function getRandom(){return Math.ceil(Math.random()* 20);}
function createSum(){
        var randomNum1 = getRandom(),
            randomNum2 = getRandom();
    total =randomNum1 + randomNum2;
  $( "#question" ).text( randomNum1 + " + " + randomNum2 + "=" );  
  $("#ans").val('');
  checkInput();
}

function checkInput(){
        var input = $("#ans").val(), 
        slideSpeed = 200,
      hasInput = !!input, 
      valid = hasInput && input == total;
    $('#message').toggle(!hasInput);
    $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !valid);  
    $('#success').toggle(valid);
    $('#fail').toggle(hasInput && !valid);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //create initial sum
    createSum();
    // On "reset button" click, generate new random sum
    $('button[type=reset]').click(createSum);
    // On user input, check value
    $( "#ans" ).keyup(checkInput);
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

#success, #fail{
    display: none;

}

#message, #success, #fail{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input, button{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 12px;
}

input{
    border: 1px solid #FFBBD7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #FFBBD7;
    padding: 2.5px 10px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover:enabled{
    background: #303030;
}

button:disabled{
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#Home {background-color: red;}
#News {background-color: green;}
#Contact {background-color: blue;}
#About {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<title>captcha</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="captcha.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  
 <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <form>
            <p id="question"></p><input id="ans" type="text">
            <div id="message">Please verify.</div>
            <div id="success">Validation complete :)</div>
            <div id="fail">Validation failed :(</div>           
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
        </form> 
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <form>
            <p id="question"></p><input id="ans" type="text">
            <div id="message">Please verify.</div>
            <div id="success">Validation complete :)</div>
            <div id="fail">Validation failed :(</div>           
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
        </form>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're using the same id for multiple elements, `id` should be unique.
My suggestion is to use `class` and make the selector "relative" to the visible tab

```js
const currentPage = $('.tabcontent:visible');
currentPage.find('.message').toggle(!hasInput); // for example
```

There are more changes of when to call each function (`createSum` and `checkInput`).

Please review the code below and tell if something is not clear or not working as expected.

```js
function openPage(pageName, elmnt, color) {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }

  // Show the specific tab content
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

  // Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
  createSum();
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


var total;

function getRandom() {
  return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 20);
}

function createSum() {
  var randomNum1 = getRandom(),
    randomNum2 = getRandom();
  total = randomNum1 + randomNum2;
  
  const currentPage = $('.tabcontent:visible');
  currentPage.find(".question").text(randomNum1 + " + " + randomNum2 + "=");
  currentPage.find(".question").val('');
  currentPage.find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
}

function checkInput() {
  var input = $(this).val(),
   slideSpeed = 200,
   hasInput = !!input,
   valid = hasInput && input == total;

  const currentPage = $('.tabcontent:visible');
  currentPage.find('.message').toggle(!hasInput);
  currentPage.find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !valid);
  currentPage.find('.success').toggle(valid);
  currentPage.find('.fail').toggle(hasInput && !valid);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // On "reset button" click, generate new random sum
  $('button[type=reset]').click(createSum);
  // On user input, check value
  $(".ans").keyup(checkInput);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style tab links */

.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.success,
.fail {
  display: none;
}

.message,
.success,
.fail {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

input,
button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 12px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #FFBBD7;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #FFBBD7;
  padding: 2.5px 10px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover:enabled {
  background: #303030;
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: default;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}


/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */

.tabcontent {
  color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

#Home {
  background-color: red;
}

#News {
  background-color: green;
}

#Contact {
  background-color: blue;
}

#About {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<title>captcha</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="captcha.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'green')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'blue')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>

<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <form>
    <p class="question"></p><input class="ans" type="text">
    <div class="message">Please verify.</div>
    <div class="success">Validation complete :)</div>
    <div class="fail">Validation failed :(</div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <form>
    <p class="question"></p><input class="ans" type="text">
    <div class="message">Please verify.</div>
    <div class="success">Validation complete :)</div>
    <div class="fail">Validation failed :(</div>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
</div>
```